# I'm having a issue with my while loop displaying two prints the second time around

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-input, do-while

This is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Proj4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String again = "y";
        final int MAX_STUDENTS = 100;
        final int MIN_EXAM = 0;
        final int MAX_EXAM = 50;
        final int MIN_FINAL = 0;
        final int MAX_FINAL = 100;

        String[] names = new String[MAX_STUDENTS];
        int[] exams = new int[MAX_STUDENTS * 4];
        int student = 1;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");

        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter the name of student " + student
                    + ": ");
            String line;
            line = s.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            names = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter score for Final Exam: ");
                    exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                }

                else {
                    System.out.print("Please enter score for Exam " + (i + 1)
                            + ": ");
                    exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                    if (student == 1) {
                        if ((exams[0] < MIN_EXAM || exams[0] > MAX_EXAM)
                                || (exams[1] < MIN_EXAM || exams[1] > MAX_EXAM)
                                || (exams[2] < MIN_EXAM || exams[2] > MAX_EXAM)) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-50 only...");
                            System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                            exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                        } else if (exams[3] < MIN_FINAL || exams[3] > MAX_FINAL) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-100 only...");
                            System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                            exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                        }
                    } else if (student == 2) {
                        if ((exams[0] < MIN_EXAM || exams[0] > MAX_EXAM)
                                || (exams[1] < MIN_EXAM || exams[1] > MAX_EXAM)
                                || (exams[2] < MIN_EXAM || exams[2] > MAX_EXAM)) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-50 only...");
                            System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                            exams[i + 4] = s.nextInt();
                        } else if (exams[3] < MIN_FINAL || exams[3] > MAX_FINAL) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-100 only...");
                            System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                            exams[i + 4] = s.nextInt();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print("do you wish to enter another? (y or n) ");
            again = s.next();
            if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                student++;
        } while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        System.out.println("***Class Results***");
        System.out
                .println(names[1]
                        + ","
                        + names[0]
                        + "   "
                        + "Exam Percentage: "
                        + ((float) (exams[0] + exams[1] + exams[2] + exams[3]) / (MAX_EXAM * 3 + MAX_FINAL))
                        * 100 + "%");
        if (student == 2)
            ;
        System.out
                .println(names[3]
                        + ","
                        + names[2]
                        + "   "
                        + "Exam Percentage: "
                        + ((float) (exams[4] + exams[5] + exams[6] + exams[7]) / (MAX_EXAM * 3 + MAX_FINAL))
                        * 100 + "%");
        if (student == 3)
            ;
        System.out
                .println(names[5]
                        + ","
                        + names[4]
                        + "   "
                        + "Exam Percentage: "
                        + ((float) (exams[8] + exams[9] + exams[10] + exams[11]) / (MAX_EXAM * 3 + MAX_FINAL))
                        * 100 + "%");
        if (student == 4)
            ;
        System.out
                .println(names[7]
                        + ","
                        + names[6]
                        + "   "
                        + "Exam Percentage: "
                        + ((float) (exams[12] + exams[13] + exams[14] + exams[15]) / (MAX_EXAM * 3 + MAX_FINAL))
                        * 100 + "%");
    }
}
```

My program seems to be running exactly the way i want/need it to, the only problem is, when i allow the program to run again it outputs two strings on the same line like this:

```
Please enter the name of student 2: Please enter score for Exam 1:
```

I don't know what to do to fix this. is there something in my code that messes up only on the second and probably 3rd and 4th times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove semicolons after ifs

```
if (student == 3)
            ; // <- remove it
    System.out.println(//...
```

because now Java understands it as

```
if (student == 3){}
System.out.println(//...
```

---

change

```
System.out.print("do you wish to enter another? (y or n) ");
again = s.next();
```

to

```
System.out.print("do you wish to enter another? (y or n) ");
again = s.nextLine();
```

`next` will not consume new line mark, so when you use `nextLine` after `next` it will consume only this new line mark and go to another instruction. Same rule apply for `nextInt`.

---

To store array of student names you could use two dimensional array of Strings

```
String[][] names = new String[MAX_STUDENTS][];
```

and store student names in each row based on student number

```
names[student] = line.split(" ");
```

To get first name of first student you will have to use this form

```
names[0][0]; //you probably know that indexes in array starts from zero
```

To get names of all students you can iterate over each rows and then over columns

```
for(int stId=0; stId<student; stId++){
   for(int nameNumber=0; nameNumber<names[stId].length; nameNumber++){
      // print names[stId][nameNumber]`
```

Comment: oh okay, i gotcha i fixed that part, but the problem was happening even bore i added those if statements

Comment: @JosephMindrup This was firs error I spotted, will try to find more, no worries :)

Comment: That actually didn't work sorry, it printed out the "do you wish to enter another? (y or n) but wouldn't let me type anything and moved on to printing out the results

Comment: Yes, that is because `nextInt` also doesn't consume new line mark. Lets test it. Try adding `s.nextLine();` after `s.nextInt();`, something like `s.nextInt();s.nextLine();` (I know it is ugly, we will make it look better later).

Comment: after every `s.nextInt()`?

Comment: doing that didn't change anything, sorry. i really don't see anything wrong with my code, and i don't understand why this is happening

Comment: @JosephMindrup could you test loop I added to answer?

Comment: that actually worked, it allowed me to enter in the next name, buut for some reason my assignments seem to be off, is there anything you can see that i did wrong, assignment wise??

Comment: @JosephMindrup yes, I focused on loop part. Beside adding `nestLine()` I commented everything after `System.out.println("***Class Results***");`

Comment: it worked sorry i didn't see the nextLine() that you changed but now the problem i believe lies with `System.out.print("Please enter the name of student " + student + ": " );
   String line;
   line = s.nextLine().toUpperCase();
   names = line.split(" ");` it overwrites the first name when doing a second student

Comment: Yes, `line.split(" ");` returns `String[]` and it is stored in `names` which is also one dimensional String[] array. To store few arrays you may use two dimensional array `String[][] names = new String[MAX_STUDENTS][];` and use it like this `names[student] = line.split(" ");` to store names of `student`. Same about `exams`.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you, im sorry, im not used to the double arrays, how would i need format the output so that the names are displayed correctly? with what i have currently it gives me `[Ljava.lang.String;@ddb1fe0,null   Exam Percentage: 90.4%
null,[Ljava.lang.String;@4367e003   Exam Percentage: 0.0%`

Comment: @JosephMindrup To print content of array you could use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names[i]));` it will print names of student number `i` in this form `[name0, name1, ...]`. Or just use this form names[i][0], names[i][1] to get name0, name1 of student number `i`.

Comment: i isn't initialized as a variable anymore because the loop closed, could i just use [student] instead?

Comment: Hey, Thank you for all your help man, i really appreciate it, i don't know if i would have been able to do this with out you. I got it all figured out though :)

Comment: @JosephMindrup glad I could help. I am also learning so know how it is :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the strings to print on a new line use println instead of print, or include a linebreak character in your string.

Comment: the problem is it wont let me enter anything on that first line, where i have to enter the name of the second student, it just skips it and goes to the enter score of exam 1, if i use println instead it just sends the `please enter score for exam1:` to the next line and still dosent let me enter